# I'm using selenium in python (Firefox webdriver) and driver.execute_script() doesn't seem to return anything

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

So i have started using selenium in python and the driver opened whatsapp in firefox. it went into a chat, and then i wrote the following code:

```
message = 'document.getElementsByClassName('FTBzM')[document.getElementsByClassName('FTBzM').length-1]'
driver.execute_script("return {}.getElementsByClassName('_F7Vk')[0].textContent".format(message))
```

but the code returns None. I have tried to execute the code in the console in firefox (without the return) and it works perfectly.

English is not my native language so if you don't understand something i will happily explain it

Comment: Have you tried printing the output like `print(driver.execute_script...)` Is it giving None? And here why you have used {} with return?

Comment: i used {} because of the way my code is structured. also, i was an idiot and it doesn't return None, i just accidentally set it later as None. i have fixed the problem, but thanks for your help! the problem was to do with the fact that in whatsapp, groups are different then personal chats, and i wasn't using something that was in group messages **and** personal messages